# Finding how many times something would occur given a chance

Tags: probability

I'm trying to calculate how many times you would succeed on 200 tries of say clicking a button but having a 0.065% chance of succeeding.

This is probably basic Probability but I can find nothing on it.

Whats the correct method of doing this?

Comment: See the subheading mean on this [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) page.

Comment: Do you mean the average number of successes?  That's $200\times.065$ There's no telling how many times you would actually succeed.

Comment: With a probability of $\binom{200}{x} \cdot 0.00065^x \cdot 0.99935^{200-x}$ you succeed $x$ times if you click the button 200 times.

Comment: What are the dots for? Are they just spacers, also how would you work out x for the first one ?